# Haskell: how can I split a string whenever there are two adjacent apostrophes?

Tags: string, haskell, split

I am doing some string work that leaves me with some repeated-single-quote strings like:

```
all''your''base''belong
```

and I want to separate the string in between the apostrophes to get a list:

```
all'
'your'
'base'
'belong
```

Or, even better, that would trim each word of the apostrophes *unless* it has an apostrophe only at the end, so the end result would be:

```
all'
your
base
belong
```

How could I go about doing this cleanly?

Comment: What's the reasoning behind leaving two `'`s in the last example?

Comment: So the idea is parsing a very long string of any chars into words, entirely letter words *unless* the word either contains or ends with a single apostrophe, which counts as part of the word. I have most of it completed but I end up with strings like the above where my functions don't handle that particular case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you are doing, it might be easier to make a real parser.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char

singleQuotedStrings = many (char '\'' *> many letter <* char '\'')

main = print $ parse singleQuotedStrings [] "'all''your''base''belong'"
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain what's happening here? What are the * > and < * operators?

Comment: `*>` and `<*` combine two `Applicative f => f x` values together by discarding one of the values. The value they keep is the one pointed at by the `>` or `<`. For parsers, the `char '\''` parser requires that a `'` be present in the input. The `*>` and `<*` operators are building a parser that still looks for those characters, but discards them and just results in the `many letter` inbetween.